# How to set default boolean value in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have an attribute

```
private boolean include;
```

I would like to set its default value to true, so that in the database it must display True from default. Is this possible in JPA?

Comment: you can use assigning to change default value.create setter method and set true value.

Comment: `private boolean include = true;` will work on Java. Still, you have to make sure your database has direct support for `boolean` fields or if you have to use a converter.

Comment: Can you try with following?

Column(name="Include ") 
private boolean include = true;

Comment: Hi there, my database is sql server, using datatype bit so it should support boolean values. i have tried the above methods in the comments but still no value displays in the database by default

Comment: I find it is always better to use `Boolean` than `boolean` when dealing with `boolean` values in  JPA. In some versions of Spring Boot, the later throws and exception when updating an entity

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As far as i known there is no JPA native solution to provide default values.
Here it comes my workaround:

**Non database portable solution**

```
@Column(columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 1")
private boolean include;
```

**Java oriented solution**

```
private boolean include = true;
```

**Java oriented plus Builder pattern**

```
     @Column(nullable = false)
     private Boolean include;
     ...
     public static class Builder {
      private Boolean include = true; // Here it comes your default value
      public Builder include (Boolean include ) {
      this.include = include ;
      return this;
     }
     // Use the pattern builder whenever you need to persist a new entity.
     public MyEntity build() {
       MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity ();
       myEntity .setinclude (include );
       return myEntity;
      }
...
}
```

This is my favorite and less intrusive. Basically it delegates the task to define the default value to the Builder pattern in your entity.

Comment: Also `@Column(columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT false")` will work for many databases include PostgreSQL.

Comment: Any idea what the JPA committee recommends developers do?

Comment: WARNING: using the columnDefinition like that makes it incompatible with SQLServer (possibly others)

Answer (score 15):

For **PostgreSQL** you can use boolean in definition

```
@Column(name = "isDeleted", columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
private boolean isDeleted = true;
```

Comment: if we are using default value in column definition , then why are you initialising to true again?

Comment: It is for hibernate. it directly considers that assigned value and insert it into table

Answer (score 12):

Using JPA 2.1 and Oracle 11 this works for me by using Oracle type NUMBER of size 1:

Java:

```
@Column(name = "ENABLED", nullable = false)
private boolean enabled = true;
```

Create SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE "ACCOUNT"(
"ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"NAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"ENABLED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe will be useful for people who work with **Microsoft SQL SERVER**

```
    @Column(columnDefinition="bit default 0")
    private Boolean active;
```

Possible values: 0 or 1

Answer (score 4):

In my case, for spring boot jpa, having the below syntax in entity class worked.

```
@Builder.Default
private boolean columnName = false;

or

@NotNull
@Builder.Default
@ColumnDefault("true")
private Boolean columnName = true;
```

@Builder.Default is to ensure we are having default values while constructing the object for this model, needed only when the entity model class is annotated with @Builder. If otherwise, even without having @Builder.Default, things are working fine as expected.

Comment: Just 
`@NotNull
@ColumnDefault("true")` is enough.

`@Builder.Default` throws an exception.

Comment: My bad should have explained a bit further, ``@Builder.Default`` can be used if we have ``@Builder`` annotation for the entity. ``@Builder`` is supported by Lombok plugin to generate beans

Comment: this answer is best solution than the others.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that adding in the constructor is a good workaround to default new entities to a value:

```
public EntityName(){
    this.fieldToDefault = default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use annotations `@PreUpdate` or `@PrePersist` on method where you will setup what should be done before update or before save into DB.

Or just simply setup the value `private boolean include = true;`

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined default values in your database, you can choose the column annotation, and as parameter you use `insertable = false`, in this way when inserting a value it will choose the one that you marked by default in the database. Example:
In MySQL I have a person table with a status attribute of boolean type and it has by default the value true.
In your java class it would look like this:

```
//....
public class Person implements Serializable {
    //.....
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private Boolean status;
    //...
}
```

You can have more information about the column annotation [HERE](https://www.oscarblancarteblog.com/2016/11/10/definicion-columnas-column/), it is well explained and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to set a default column value is to set it directly as an entity property value:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name = "Ousama";
    private Integer age = 30;
    private Boolean happy = false;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is when playing with repository like Example.of method. With the above solution if I need to search only for name = "Adam" then the search will also include age and happy by default to search and  developer has to always remove such default values

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MYSQL, I can save your 5-6 hours which you will waste if searching for the answer. I tried multiple ways but for me updating the maven dependency version of spring boot data jpa in pom.xml file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Lombok builder then do not forget to add @Builder.Default annotation:

```java
@Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
@Builder.Default
private boolean include = false;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private boolean include = true;
```

Comment: Hi  Try adding some explanation to give context to your code rater than just pasting code.  Although it may make perfect sense to you, it would be better to explain it.

Comment: Your value will be overwritten by the database value during read, so this isn't a solution.