# JPA EclipseLink: handle default value

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, default-value

I have the following column definition:

```
@Column(name="active", nullable=false, columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE"
private Boolean active;
```

In the Postgres database the column `active` is defined as `BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE`

But when I insert a new record, without setting `active`, EclipseLink generates a `null` value for this field and the insert statement obviously fails because Postgres does not allow a `null` value for the `NOT NULL` column.

What am I doing wrong?

Well, if I define my field as

```
private boolean active;
```

then I will indirectly set the field to false. But I cannot use this trick with `Date` fields. So, I am looking for a solution which will work for all column types.

Comment: JPA doesn't natively support this feature, but this is what you should do - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28208792/4116955

Comment: I am suggesting the "Non database portable solution", given in this answer, in my post. However, it will work only for `boolean`. For other types, I can only use the "Java oriented solution".

Comment: What I don't understand is how `columnDefinition` works. Why should I put it there in the java code when it does not have an effect?

Actually, I don't understand the "Non database portable solution" - it only works because they use `boolean`, not `Boolean` and thus they always have default `false`. This is the same as the "Java oriented solution". If the idea was that the annotation was important - I don't see how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `columnDefinition` is only used for the DDL creation and can be database specific. You may have problems switching the DB if you use it.

Using primitive types ensures that the value is not null, and without explicitly defining a value, the primitive's default is used. However, you can also define default values for non-primitive values by assigning them: `private Boolean active = false;`
That will also work with `Date`.

When you need complex default values you can use the `PrePersist` annotation:

```
    @PrePersist
    public void setDefaultValues() {
        if (active == null) {
            active = false;
        }
        if (value == null) {
           //do complex stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you NEVER are going to set the attribute, you can use  `@Column (insertable = false)`, if you set a value, this will be ignored anyway.
This is a very common setting on Date like

```
@Column(nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date systemDate;
```